# RabbitMQ has greater latency than other MQ

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, benchmarking

I just finished reading an Message Queue Benchmark article. The article compares the 4 most popular message queue types(including Redis). I was quite surprised about lantency of RabbitMQ compared to other MQ.
[image]

I asked the question whether the its novel exchange mechanism which effect to latency?

Benchmark Article: https://www.mdpi.com/2673-4001/4/2/18